# The elements of dropdown menu with fontawesome haven't the same size (CSS3 Family tree)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, tree

I have css3 family tree that when you click on the box a drop-down menu appears.

The div's in the drop-down menu for some reason are not the same size.

For example:

When opening the menu of sub department of department 3 the edit option is bigger than add.
On the other hand, if you open the menu of the entity or department 3, it seems to be the same size.

How can i fix it ?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="tree d-flex justify-content-center">
        <!-- BEGIN ORGANIGRAM-->
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Entity<hr>User 1<br> User2</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">          
                <div>              
                  <a title="Add new" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal_organigram" data-id="1" data-type="1" data-select="undefined" data-title="Entity">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>              
                  </a>            
                </div>            
                <div class="mt-1">              
                  <a title="Modify" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal_modify" data-id="1" data-type="1" data-parent="undefined" data-select="undefined" data-title="Entity">                
                    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>           
                  </a>            
                </div>          
              </div>              
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Department 3<hr>User 1<br></a>          
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">            
                    <div>              
                      <a title="Add new" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal_organigram" data-id="4" data-type="2" data-select="3" data-title="Department 3">                
                        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>              
                      </a>            
                    </div>            
                    <div class="mt-1">              
                      <a title="Modify" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal_modify" data-id="4" data-type="2" data-parent="1" data-select="3" data-title="Department 3">                
                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>              
                      </a>            
                    </div>          
                  </div>

                </div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Subdepartment<hr>User 6 <br> User 3</a>          
                      <div class="dropdown-menu">            
                        <div>              
                          <a title="Add new" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal_organigram" data-id="6" data-type="3" data-select="" data-title="Subdepartment">                
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>              
                          </a>            
                        </div>            
                        <div class="mt-1">              
                          <a title="Modify" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal_modify" data-id="6" data-type="3" data-parent="4" data-select="" data-title="Subdepartment">
                            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>           
                          </a>            
                        </div>          
                      </div>

                    </div>

                  </li>

                </ul>

              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Department 4<hr>User 7<br></a>          
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">            
                    <div>              
                      <a title="Add new" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal_organigram" data-id="5" data-type="2" data-select="4" data-title="Department 4">                
                        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>              
                      </a>            
                    </div>            
                    <div class="mt-1">              
                      <a title="Modify" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal_modify" data-id="5" data-type="2" data-parent="1" data-select="Futbol" data-title="Department 4">                
                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>            
                      </a>            
                     </div>          
                  </div>

                </div>

              </li>

            </ul>

          </li>

        </ul>
        <!-- END ORGANIGRAM-->
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.tree ul {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: unset;
  padding-top: 20px; 
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; 
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 6px 0 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, 
.tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; 
    height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after{
    right: auto; 
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, 
.tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ 
  padding-top: 0;
}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, 
.tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}

/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, 
.tree li div:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; 
    color: #000 !important; 
    border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li div:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li div:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li div:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li div:hover+ul ul::before{
  border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

.tree li a hr{
  margin-top:0.5rem;
  margin-bottom:0.5rem;
}

.tree div.dropdown { 
  display:inline-block; 
}

.tree .dropdown-toggle::after{
  content:none;
 }

.tree div.dropdown-menu{
  border: none;
  background-color: unset;
  box-shadow: none;
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: unset !important;
  right: -37px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/cplaiuu/pen/gOpmGQJ)

[image]

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Adding style `min-width:` to the a tags solves the problem.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You can just assign min-width:35px to both your button.

Comment: @DenPat first question its works thanks.
Do you have any suggestions for the second question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is caused by the fact that there is a `pt-1` `class` in the second `div`, while there is no such `class` in the first `div`.

`pt-1` has the rule of

```
.pt-1, .py-1 {
    padding-top: .25rem!important;
}
```

which causes the problem, since due to this `padding-top` more size is needed to properly display the item. Change the rule to

```
.pt-1, .py-1 {
    margin-top: .25rem!important;
}
```

Using mt-1 instead of pt-1

[image]

EDIT

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have changed from pt-1 to mt-1 but still have the same problem. Instead with min-width as @DenPat says it has worked. 
Thank you anyway.

Do you have any suggestions for the second question ?

Comment: @cplaiuu it worked for me, see the screenshot in my edited answer, taken from your codepan.

Comment: @cplaiuu as about your second question, take a look at ```.tree li a:hover, 
.tree li div:hover+ul li a {```. This will apply to the children as well. Make it more specific, like ```.tree li > div > a:hover, 
.tree li div:hover+ul li a {```

Comment: If I comment this min-width:35px; text-align:center; of class .a-menu-dropdown and change pt-1 to mt-1 the size of div's still different.

Comment: @cplaiuu you don't need to comment that out.